# Does Russia benefit from the Belt and Road Initiative?

Tags: russian-federation, china, international, belt-and-road-initiative

[image]

I was looking at this map and it seems that Russia is not confirmed to be a member of the Belt and Road Initiative(BRI). I am wondering if Russia expressed any view that might indicate they're not too fond of it, and what might be the negative consequences of the BRI that might hamper Russia in any way. Because of the reliance Russia has on China, it seems they may not express any concern they have against the BRI, so I am suspecting there to be some reasons why Russia won't openly support it or join it.

Comment: Asked before https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/russia-in-belt-and-road-initiative BTW there are some recent stupid changes to the SE software so Qs with non-positive answer scores can't be voted as duplicate anymore, but the zero-net-score answer there (+1-1) addresses exactly this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the state of participation by Russia in the Belt and Road Initiative?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/what-is-the-state-of-participation-by-russia-in-the-belt-and-road-initiative)

Comment: I believe that Russia does not explicitly participate in BRI because it has its own [EEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_Economic_Union).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BRI is the idea of China, but an impressions about Russia role in it you may conclude from this [photo](https://www.yidaiyilu.gov.cn/p/02HNGCMF.html):

[image]

V.V. Putin is on the right hand from Xí Jìnpíng, Xí's wife Péng Lìyuán is on
the left hand.

The map you had posted is not an original one, it was created by the media agency. And now they have posted [another maps](https://www.cfr.org/blog/chinas-belt-and-road-initiative-enters-its-second-decade-which-leaders-went-beijing-celebrate) with Russia including.

Russia also have own economy initiative [Greater Eurasian Partnership(GEP)](https://www.russia-briefing.com/news/russia-s-2023-foreign-policy-concept-central-asia.html/) and not only. Both BRI and GEP will be associated systems.

> Russia’s Foreign Policy Concept is highly focused on Central Asia and a new commitment in turns of institutionalizing this along with
> Eurasia has been made. This is multi-formatted, with the
> Russia-Central Asian annual Heads of State summit and of course the
> even wider Shanghai Cooperation Organisation’s reach.
>
> There also appears a longer-term strategy to introduce the Eurasian
> Economic Unions’ Free Trade capabilities to a wider group, including
> members of the SCO. Iran has a FTA with the EAEU, while India is close
> to finalizing one.
>
> Not mentioned specifically in the context of Central Asia, but
> certainly implied elsewhere in the Concept is the developing BRICS and
> BRICS plus and their potential evolution into a larger Free Trade
> Area. Bangladesh, Egypt, and the UAE have all recently joined as de
> facto members. Another 13 countries are discussing this.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if Russia exactly benefits from anything these days. Even if they joined BRI in [2020](https://greenfdc.org/countries-of-the-belt-and-road-initiative-bri/), they will never admit it.

Comment: This answer should be expanded some to avoid the downvotes, despite the 2nd sentence being true. Russia would never publicly join another country's organization. The BRI is too much China's initiative. Russia, if they do join, will do so in a manner that separates themselves from other members. Russia will only be a founding member, or leading member, or privileged member. Their view is that joining another organization would make them appear subordinate to the leading country of that org.