# Do the trains of the silk road freight line fall into the scope of the Russian sanctions?

Tags: russian-federation, china, sanctions

The [Silk Road train line](http://english.scio.gov.cn/beltandroad/2021-11/29/content_77899296.htm) is a freight line connecting China and Europe. The service is still [operational](https://www.newsilkroaddiscovery.com/china-europe-freight-trains-transported-774000teus-from-jan-to-may-increased-31/). But online information does not tell whether the trains still go via the Russian Federation. So I am wondering whether it happens and whether they are subjet to the sanctions agains the Russians or not. I do not mean to ask whether they trade with them, the trains that pass through thei Russian rail network will have to pay to use the network and provide some money to the Russian economy even without direct trade.

What is the current situation?

There is a [related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/what-is-the-state-of-participation-by-russia-in-the-belt-and-road-initiative), but the answers are too vague.

There is another [related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78556/does-russia-benefit-from-the-belt-and-road-initiative), but it has a broader context, still open to vague answers although there are no answers for the moment.

Comment: Sanctions are frequently being updated but while the EU prohibited exports from Russia, [as of December 2022](https://finance.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-12/faqs-sanctions-russia-transit-listed-goods_en.pdf) they didn't prohibit the transit of all goods by rail. You can view detailed information on sanctions online, but it is very complicated, changes a lot, and depends on the country. But some rail transit has been allowed.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you. Your comment could be an answer.

Comment: How could a train connecting China with Europe not pass through the Russian Federation? Should it traverse the Himalaya or the Alai? (And since we are talking politics here, if there was a hypothetical train route, you would end up in Iran - even more sanctions to consider.)

Comment: The train could go via Kazakstan, Turkmenistan, cross the Caspian on a Ferry, to Baku than via Turkey to Europe.

Comment: @JamesK That's the [Lapis Lazuli corridor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapis_Lazuli_corridor), but it would be too expensive and cumbersome for trains directed to Germany. The stated objective that you can read in that page seems just a publicity stunt.

Comment: But that *is* the route of the Chang-an train line - Via the Caspian, not via Russia.